# VirtualBox not installing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am trying to get VirtualBox working on my 14.04 LTS machine.
After installing I keep getting this error:

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly     installed.
Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please  find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.
```

After installing I got this error:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                            No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.10 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-26-generic
Building initial module for 3.19.0-26-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                            * No suitable module for running kernel found
```

Comment: What errors are shown in  `/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you're trying to install vagrant, that requires virtualbox to be installed, so try to install it explicitly first

i see 3 different versions available to install

```
virtualbox-4.2 - Oracle VM VirtualBox
virtualbox-4.3 - Oracle VM VirtualBox
virtualbox-5.0 - Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

Install with this command ( version 5.0 has USB 3.0 support ), this will also install the necessary kernel modules

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a different version of my kernel headers and my kernel. To test this, take a look at the output of

```
uname -r
```

and compare that to the folders in

```
/lib/modules
```

if they are different, first use apt-get to remove the kernel headers and then use

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

to install the headers and kernel for the correct version. After this you may have to reinstall virtualbox and/or use

```
modprobe vboxdrv
```

but you should be up and running.